# Where to implement navigation code to move next screen with redux and react-navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm building a mobile app with `react-native`, `redux`, and `react-navigation`.

I have been thinking which code should have a function that is about screen transition(ex. `this.props.navigation.navigate('NextScreen')`).

For example, in my app, sign in process is below.

[Sign In Process](https://gyazo.com/59063977eea304a4ad44724eafb78c0b)

As you see, the app runs `this.props.navigation.navigate()` in handleSignIn function in SignIn screen.

[Questions]

- Sometimes the `uid` value in state is blank, it should be filled if user sign in successfully, but sometimes not. How do I solve it?
- `this.props.navigator.navigator()` is executed in the function that is defined in the screen component, is it good?

There are my code.

- SignIn Screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

: 

class SignIn extends Component {

  async handleSignIn() {
    const { navigation, requestSignIn } = this.props;
    const { uid, email, password, error } = this.props.auth;
    Keyboard.dismiss();

    requestSignIn(email, password);

    // sometimes this uid is blank
    if (uid) {
      alert('success');

      // this function should be executed here?
      navigation.navigate('Match', { uid: uid });
    } else {
      alert(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation, changeText } = this.props;
    const { email, password, loading } = this.props.auth;

    return (
     :
            <Button gradient onPress={() => this.handleSignIn()}>
              { loading ?
                <ActivityIndicator size='small' color='white' /> :
                <Text bold white center>Sign In</Text>
              }
            </Button>
     :
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    auth: state.auth
  }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    requestSignIn: (email, password) => dispatch(auth.requestSignIn(email, password)),
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn);

:
```

- Action

```
:
export const REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS = 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS';
export const REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE = 'REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE';

export function requestSignIn(email, password) {
  return async function (dispatch) {
    // change loading status
    dispatch(startedRequest());

    if (email && password) {
      await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(response => {
          if (response) {
            // save email and password in local secure storage.
            SecureStorage.setItem('email', email);
            SecureStorage.setItem('password', password);

            dispatch(requestSignInSuccess(response.user.uid))
          } else {
            return Promise.resolve(new Error(response));
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          switch (error.code) {
            case 'auth/user-not-found':
              dispatch(requestSignInFailure('user not found'));
              break;
            case 'auth/invalid-email':
              dispatch(requestSignInFailure('invalid email'));
              break;
            default:
              dispatch(requestSignInFailure('something went wrong'))
          }
        })

    } else {
      dispatch(requestSignInFailure('error message from else statement'))
    }
  }
}

export function requestSignInSuccess(uid) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS,
    payload: {
      uid: uid
    }
  }
}

export function requestSignInFailure(errorMessage) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE,
    payload: {
      errorMessage: errorMessage
    }
  }
}
```

- Reducer

```
import * as ActionType from '../actions/auth';

const initialState = {
  uid: '',
  email: '',
  password: '',
  isLoading: false,
  error: {
    message: ''
  }
};

const auth = (state=initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case ActionType.STARTED_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoading: true
      });
    case ActionType.CHANGE_TEXT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [payload.key]: payload.value
      });
    case ActionType.REQUEST_SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        uid: payload.uid,
        isLoading: false,
      });
    case ActionType.REQUEST_SIGN_IN_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isLoading: false,
        error: {
          message: payload.errorMessage,
        },
      });
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

export default auth;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, yes you should navigate into the component after your sign-in business logic works.

About the second question, it is wrong with using "requestSignIn" method. You need to send a callback from requestSignIn method and it should something like this:

```
requestSignIn((result) => {
  if(result){
    const { uid } = result;
    uid && navigate("Match", {uid});
  }
})
```

As I can see in your action, you already send a dispatch, therefore, it should work as the above example.

### Why it is not working with your logic?

It is so simple because it is not working sync, it just goes to the next if check so it does not wait until the requestSignIn method is finished. You can even use async/await but dispatch (Promise) will solve it for you :)

One last thing, I suggest you to use [React Navigation Helpers](https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-navigation-helpers) for handling all navigation logics. I've written it and it solves so many dirty logic for you :)

Answer (score 0):

About the second question, I follow this link.

https://github.com/daose/react-native-template/issues/1

Finally, I use `NavigationActions` in the action instead of `this.props.navigation.navigate()`